# Python class property decorators not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

I'm trying to get Python's decorators to work for me. I'm having trouble understanding why this doesn't work:

```
class toy(object):

    @property
    def toyname(self):
        return 'lol'

a = toy
print(a.toyname)
```

when I run it, I get the following output:

```
<property object at 0x03362FC0>
```

The property, it seems, is not being evaluated.

I've seen several answers for Python 2.x mention that I need to subclass `object` in order for properties to work; however, the answers I've come across so far do not solve my problem.

Comment: Are you trying to create a _class_ property or an _instance_ property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the line `a = toy` that is causing a problem. What `a = toy` means is saying is "point the variable `a` to the definition of the class `toy`". What you actually want to do is `a = toy()`, to instantiate an object of type `toy` and save it in `a`.

Comment: Thank you! That was my problem. This was such an infuriating error to run into!

Answer (score 1):

`toy` is the blueprint for your class. `toy()` is a new copy of the class that you can work with, or a new instance. You need to "instantiate" it, which means you need to create a new instance of the class to assign to a. In other words, you need `a = toy()` instead of `a = toy`

Try this:

```
class toy(object):
    @property
    def toyname(self):
        return 'lol'

a = toy()
print(a.toyname)
```